# Extract Unique Element ID using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Okay, so I have a form which adds an item to a list of items and does calculations with it, but every new item thats added is done on the users side before being submitted to the server for verification and updating of database. Now, I've looked at other answers and couldnt really get an answer. If the user adds a new item and enter a quantity and rate it should calculate the amount automatically, how would one extract the unique ID identifier to change the value of the amount? The code below and in this case the unique identifier is 19786868. The length of this identifier is always different and their is no unique pattern, the length and value is generated by a random command.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_quantity" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_rate" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_amount" />
```

How would I extract this unique identifier with the OnChange command in JavaScript to calculate the amount value?

Comment: _"how would one extract the unique ID identifier to change the value of the amount?"_ Is requirement to retrieve number portion of element `id`?

Comment: @guest271314 , how else would I work with the amount input, there are more than just one amount input in the form, would one need to get the ID to then use it in a function?

Comment: _"there are more than just one amount input in the form"_ Is each `id` unique? _"would one need to get the ID to then use it in a function?"_ Are you trying to sum quantity and rate and display result at amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_quantity" onchange="extractId(event);"/>
```

And in javascript :

```
function extractId(event) {
 var elem = event.target;
 var myArr = elem.id.split('_');

 var yourUnique_id = myArr[3];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jeremy-denis, will give this a try

Comment: i forgot the event in my html in my function on change i add it

Answer (score 3):

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".form-control"), function(el) {

  var id = el.id.replace(/\D+/g,"");
  console.log( id );       // "19786868"

});
```

so basically use a `this.id.replace(/\D+/g,"")` where all non Digit `\D` gets replaced by `""`

Here's an **example using the `input` event**:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".form-control"), function(el) {

  el.addEventListener("input", function() {
    var id = this.id.replace(/\D+/g,"");
    alert( id );
  }, false)

});
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_quantity" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_123_foobar" />
```

<sub>Take note that: `asd_123_foo_9` will return `1239` as result so make sure to always have `asd_123_foo` as `ID` value</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> If the user adds a new item and enter a quantity and rate it should
>   calculate the amount automatically, how would one extract the unique
>   ID identifier to change the value of the amount?

You can use `input` event; `for` loop; attribute contains selector `[attributeName*=containsString]`, `.nextElementSibling`, `.previousElementSibling`,  to sum values of `id` containing `"quantity"` and `id` containing `"rate"` and set result at `id` containing `"amount"`

```js
function calculate() {
  this.parentElement.querySelector("[id*=amount]")
  .value = +this.value 
       + +(/quantity/.test(this.id)
           ? this.nextElementSibling 
           : this.previousElementSibling 
          ).value
}

var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[id*=quantity], [id*=rate]");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  calculate.call(elems[i]); elems[i].oninput = calculate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_quantity" value="1" />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_rate" value="2" />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_amount" />
</div>
<div>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786867_quantity" value="3" />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786867_rate" value="4" />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786867_amount" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to respond to newly added input controls, you need to capture the `change` event at some parent element, otherwise you will not trap the change on newly added elements.

Here is some code that handles the change event on the document. As this event bubbles up, it will eventually get there, so we can respond to it:

For extracting the number from the input's id, we can use a regular expression:

```js
document.onchange = function(e) {
    var match = e.target.id.match(/^(list_item_attributes_.*?_)(rate|quantity)$/);
    if (!match) return; // not rate or quantity
    // read rate and quantity for same ID number:
    var rate = +document.querySelector('#' + match[1] + 'rate').value;
    var quantity = +document.querySelector('#' + match[1] + 'quantity').value;
    // write product as amount:
    document.querySelector('#' + match[1] + 'amount').value = rate*quantity;
}
```

```html
Quantity: <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_quantity" /><br>
Rate: <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_rate" /><br>
Amount: <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_amount" /><br>
<p>
Quantity: <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_14981684_quantity" /><br>
Rate: <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_14981684_rate" /><br>
Amount: <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_14981684_amount" /><br>
```

As you have asked to respond to the `change` event, I have kept it that way, but you might be interested to use the `input` event instead, which will trigger as soon as any character changes in an input.

The above sample does not protect the `amount` fields from input. You should probably do something about that, because users could just overwrite the calculated result.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector(".my-form").addEventListener("change", function(e) {

  var changed = e.target;
  var matchedId = changed.id.match(/^(list_item_attributes_[^_]*)_/);
  if (!matchedId) {
    // this isn't one of the relevant fields
    return;
  }
  var uniquePrefix = matchedId[1];
  var quantity = document.querySelector("#" + uniquePrefix + "_quantity");
  var rate = document.querySelector("#" + uniquePrefix + "_rate");
  var amount = document.querySelector("#" + uniquePrefix + "_amount");
  var newVal = quantity.value * rate.value;
  if (isNaN(quantity.value) || isNaN(rate.value) || isNaN(newVal)) {

    amount.value = "";

  } else {

    amount.value = newVal;

  }

});
```

```html
<form class="my-form">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_quantity" />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_rate" />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list_item_attributes_19786868_amount" />
</form>
```

Comment: This could be shortened, but I've kept it a bit more verbose to show the working.